# bash script to find the product of two numbers in succession up to a max number

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, git-bash

I have used shellcheck.net, and the script runs but the output is not as I expected it to be here is the script and output and again I am trying to get the script to show the results of 1*2 2*3 3*4 etc... up to the given max number for the range and display a count as it goes like 1. 2. 3. etc... any input would help greatly.

```
#!/bin/bash
#A script to find the products of two nonnegative numbers in succession to each other up to a maximum number
a=1
b=2
prod=$((a*b))
count=1
echo "Input The max number to find product of numbers in succession with each other up to."
read -r maxnum
echo "Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to $maxnum are as follows."
for (( b=2; b<=maxnum; ++b ))
do
        for (( a=1; a<b; ++a ))
        do
                for (( count=1; count<=maxnum; ++count ))
                do
                        echo "$count. $prod"
                done
        done
done
echo "You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other"
```

**Ouput**

```
Input The max number to find product of numbers in succesion with each other up to.
5
Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to 5 are as follows.
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2 
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succesion to each other
```

Comment: Please redit your Q using only `2` as your argument. Then include your expected output for that input, please. Good luck.

Comment: It looks like you're setting `prod` before the loops, but never updating it; hence, it never changes value from "2".

Comment: When you do `a=1; b=2; prod=$((a*b))` it will use the current value of `a` and `b`, and be equivalent to `prod=2`. If you change `a` or `b` and want `prod` to be the new product, you should do `prod=$((a*b))` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling together various comments from this (and the previous) question, and doing a bit of cleanup:

```
$ cat abc.bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Input The max number to find product of numbers in succession with each other up to."

read -r maxnum

echo "Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to $maxnum are as follows."

for (( a=1; a<maxnum; a++ ))
do
    printf "%s.%s\n" "${a}" $((a*(a+1)))
done

echo "You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other"
```

A couple sample runs:

```
$ abc.bash
Input The max number to find product of numbers in succession with each other up to.
3
Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to 3 are as follows.
1.2
2.6
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other

$ abc.bash
Input The max number to find product of numbers in succession with each other up to.
5
Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to 5 are as follows.
1.2
2.6
3.12
4.20
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other
```

**NOTE**: May need to come back and tweak the code depending on the OP's desired output (still to be added to the question).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#A script to find the products of two nonnegative numbers in succession to each other up to a maximum number
echo "Input The max number to find product of numbers in succession with each other up to."
read -r maxnum
echo "Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to $maxnum are as follows."
for (( count=1; count<maxnum; ++count ))
do
    a=$count
    b=$((count+1))
    prod=$((a*b))
    echo "$count. $prod"
done
echo "You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other"
```

There is no need to use so many for loops. With only one count of the iteration you can define both consecutive numbers a=count and b=count+1 until maxnum is reached. Also this is the only way you index properly your iterations, since in your code you are repeating your count for two more unnecesary loops iterating a and b.

Additionally you should establish as condition, that your read maxnum should not be less than 2, otherwise you have no two consecutive numbers to multiply.